# How to avoid PlayerInterruptedException (Connection aborted) from just audio inside TabBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, audio-player, just-audio

I am using `just_audio: ^0.9.29` to play the audio. The page contains `TabBar()` with `Two Tabs`. The player is inside the first Tab.

**AudioPlayer Code:**

```
    GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => taskerProfileViewModel.playAudio(),
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: kBlack,
      child: taskerProfileViewModel.isPlaying.value
          ? const Icon(
              Icons.pause,
              color: kWhite,
            )
          : const Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow,
              color: kWhite,
            ),
    ),
  );

void setAudioUrl({required String url}) async {
    audioPlayer.setUrl("$baseUrl/$url", initialPosition: Duration.zero);
    Duration? audioDuration;
    try {
      audioDuration = await audioPlayer.load();
    } on PlayerInterruptedException catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Exception $e");
      }
    }
    if (audioDuration != null) {
      audioEndTime.value =
          "${audioDuration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}:${audioDuration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}";
    }
  }
```

I am calling the `setAudioUrl()` function in the `initstate`.

When i swap the tab there is no issue. But, When I tap on the tab, the audio player is throwing this exception `PlayerInterruptedException (Connection aborted)`.

How do I catch and ignore this exception?

Answer (score 1):

the `setUrl` should be inside the `try catch` block and it's an asynchronous method so it needs an `await` keyword, try this piece of code:

```
    void setAudioUrl({required String url}) async {
    Duration? audioDuration;
    try {
    await audioPlayer.setUrl("$baseUrl/$url", initialPosition: Duration.zero);
    audioDuration = await audioPlayer.load();
    } on PlayerInterruptedException catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Exception $e");
      }
    }
    if (audioDuration != null) {
      audioEndTime.value =
          "${audioDuration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}:${audioDuration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}";
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps.